# Any twitter bootstrap hosting options

Tags: web-services, twitter-bootstrap, web-hosting

I want to use the twitter bootstrap framework fort website. From what I understand I will need to install node js on my host. 
Although most hosting services does not allow you toinstall software on the system.

Are there any hosting services which help me use twitter bootstrap framework ?

Comment: Install node.js to run the bootstrap? Twitter Bootstrap is simply a front-end collection of tools for rapid website creation, you can use it anywhere.

Comment: doesn't 'lesscss' require a server side component ? Or am I understanding something wrong ?

Comment: less is a js script, you can include it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special requirement to run node.js on the server. Any normal shared hosting will support this .js file.

Answer (score 0):

This is hosting dedicated to host static Bootstrap websites - http://www.bootstrap.hosting/